# signalr on function not being called

Tags: android, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using signalR client java for an android application. 
The following is the code i am trying as of now:

```
conn = new HubConnection("http://example.com/");
hubProxy = conn.createHubProxy("android");

hubProxy.on("request", new SubscriptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        testFunction();
    }
});

conn.start().done(new Action<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void run(Void obj) throws Exception {
        hubProxy.invoke("init");
    }
});
```

The following are tested and verified as working:

1. The conn has surely started and the connection is successful. I am able to use sever functions using invoke. Even the invoke("init") is confirmed to be working.
2. The "request" function is definitely being called. I have checked in several ways including creating an equivalent code on js with a console.log. It works perfectly with the same process.
   `hub.on('request', function(){console.log(99)})`
3. I have tried running the testFunction() else where and it works perfectly.

I have basically done every possible check I could think of on every part of the process. The issue I am facing is that I have the testFunction() never runs when the request is called. I have tried replacing it with several other codes. None of them run. I have tested on the android studio emulator and on the phone after generating an apk file. Based on my tests  mentioned above, what could be the possible reasons why the on function is still not called?

Comment: Were you able to get it working? I updated my answer with new information.

Answer (score 1):

When you register to a method on a hub, your callback doesn't get called immediately. The library first processes the data it retrieves. If an error occurs, your callback won't get called. This is mainly because deserialization fails.

You can attach a Logger to your connection. This allows you to log data about the requests:

```
Logger logger = new Logger() {
                @Override
                public void log(String s, LogLevel logLevel) {
                    Timber.d("SignalR " + s);
                }
            };
connection = new HubConnection(host, "", true, logger);
```

You can also attach an errorcallback to your connection. You get notified when an error occured.

```
connection.error(new ErrorCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    Log.e("signalRError",error);
                }
            });
```

A few errors I encountered were:

Deserialization would fail if null was sent back. This occured for me because the server was sending back null to keep the connection open.
As a workaround I cached `NullPointerException` and `EndOfFileException` in the `readToEnd` method in the `StreamResponse` class in the SignalR client-SDK.

Deserialization also failed for me, when I tried to deserialize a date retrieved from a API method to a `java.sql.Date`. There was a pullrequest for this issue.

In your case if the request method is already returning data, deserialization might fail, because the expected type isn't passed to the `SubscriptionHandler`.

```
hubProxy.on("request", new SubscriptionHandler1<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void run(Object object) {
        testFunction();
    }
});
```

Deserialization will also fail when you are passing `ClassA` to your `SubscriptionHandler` but the returned result is of type `ClassB`

I added the SignalR-client-SDK and the SignalR-client-SDK-Android to my project as modules to make it easier to debug, and alter code if necessary. Since the last commit was almost two years ago, and the library doesn't seem supported anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Rockney said

> "When you register to a method on a hub, your callback doesn't get
>   called immediately. "

But when you called it in right time (after hub proxy is ready).
For me was to change method from

hubProxy.on() ---> hubConnection.received()

example (in kotlin)

```
hubConnection?.received({ jsonElement ->

})
```