# SignalR Error: Failed to bind arguments received in invocation '(null)'

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-signalr

In my SignalR client (WinForms) I'm getting the following exception on just one method. The callback code is:

```
onUpdate = Client.HubService.On<Job>("MyMethod", o => MyMethod(o));
```

And the exception is:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection: Error: Failed to bind arguments received in invocation '(null)' of 'MyMethod'.
> System.InvalidOperationException: There are no callbacks registered for the method 'MyMethod'
> bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.ConnectionState.Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IInvocationBinder.GetParameterTypes(String methodName)
> bei Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.ParseMessage(ReadOnlySequence`1 input, IInvocationBinder binder)

The call in the server is:

```
await hubContext.Clients.All.MyMethod(entity);
```

Everything looks like it's setup correctly. However I always get the exception.

What am I missing?

Comment: May be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/48619149/1398461

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the method `.On<Job>("MyMethod", o => MyMethod(o));` is configured the  before it gets invoked, I faced a similar issue and found out my method was configured after it got invoked.